# Wildcard CSR generation through IIS6

Tags: iis-6, ssl-certificate, csr

What is hopefully an easy question for someone familiar with generating CSRs from IIS6:

When generating the CSR, do I just select any SINGLE site in IIS that the wildcard certificate will be used for and then enter "*.mydomainname.com" into the Common Name?

I just want to double check that by generating a CSR from a single website in IIS, and only entering the "wildcard*" in the Common Name of the request, that's all I require for a wildcard CSR. In other words, I don't need anything other than the "Common Name" in the CSR itself to indicate that it's a wildcard request.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used IIS, but generating a CSR with a common name of '*.example.org' should be exactly what you want to do.  You shouldn't have to do anything special beyond that.